# Set the build context of docker-compose to a different directory than the docker-compse.yml file

Tags: docker-compose

## My Problem

I have an app with 3 containers - a DB, a tester, and a server. My code structure is as follows:

```sh
.
├── Makefile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── postgres
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── create_fixtures.sql
│   ├── server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── tests
│       └── Dockerfile
├── server
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── server.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

I would like to keep all docker data inside the `docker` directory but have the build context set to the root directory so that it can copy the `server` and `tests` directories to their respective images.

## What Have I Tried

### Does not work

```sh
$ docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: resolve : lstat /Users/adamatan/repos/anda-app/docker/docker: no such file or directory
```

In other words, the build context seems to be the location of the `docker-compose` file. I want to decouple it.

### Works

```sh
$ docker-compose up
```

Which takes the `docker-compose.yml` file from the root dir.

This [has been reported in Docker's git repo](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4857), but I'm not sure if there's a good way to overcome it.

## My Question

**How can I set the build context of a `docker-compose up` action to a root directory, but use a `docker-compose.yml` file from one of its subdirectories?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the work-around is found in this [bug comment here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7350#issuecomment-868468196):

> In case someone also gets to this ticket with the same issue. When
> specifying "." for context it will use the current directory that the
> compose file is located within. If you want to reference the compose
> file and related Dockerfile from the current directory you are running
> from you either need to specify full paths or use ${PWD} for context.
> I kinda wish it would use the current working directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to try with the following approach:
From:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── postgres
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── create_fixtures.sql
│   ├── server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── tests
│       └── Dockerfile
├── server
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── server.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

Change to:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── docker-compose.yml
|
|-- postgres
|    |--- Dockerfile
|    |--- create.sql
|
├── server
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── server.py
|   |-- Dockerfile
|
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
    |-- Dockerfile
```

Now, within docker-compose.yml assuming you use version 3+

Set the service as follows:

```
networks:
 app_net:
volumes:
 postgres_data:

services:
database:
    image: example/database
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: postgres/.dbenv # If you want to send some env vars
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres/Dockerfile
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_USER: example
    
    ports:
      - 9332:5432
    networks:
      - app_network
```

.dbenv will contain the following:

```
DBFILE=postgres/create.sql # This can also be achieved using args in docker-compose itself.
```

The Dockerfile should also ensure that the COPY happens correctly from the source to destination. An example for your reference:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/postgres
COPY ./postgres .
... Do something with it...
```

In the same way as database service you can also set up server and tests it will be build and started as expected. I also realized that you would like to keep docker stuff within docker.

I think if you may be play around with the build context as I have suggested around with your folder structure it will work as well. Furthermore, I think the solution to your problem will be to pass the context as `context: ./docker/postgres` and the `dockerfile: Dockerfile`